# C# - Execute on Datagrid the Selected Date From and To

Tags: c#, datagrid

I am creating some schedule output using dateTimePicture in C# toolbox(Format of Short) on the datagrid. I just want is when the user choose the date "From" and "To" and click the button execute, the dategrid will automatically output the date starting "From" and end on "To". Any ideas? Please just comment your ideas below. Thank you guys!

Here's my code

```
private void btn_execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     String from = date_from.Text;
     String to = date_to.Text;

     int count;
     for(count = 0; count < to; count++)
     {
         dgv_result.Rows.Add(1);
         dgv_result.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value = from;
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `from` its keyword. You can use `fromDate` or `dateFrom`

Comment: Okay sir I'll edit my code above. :D

Comment: Sir I'm done editing it.

Comment: The code will run if the btn_execute is click. :D

Comment: Do you want to get fromDate and toDate from DataGridView on button click?

Comment: Yes sir. Exactly. I want it to be something like this, If I choose the "From" 7/8/2015 and "To" to 7/10/2015, so the datagrid will execute 7/8/2015,7/9/2015,7/10/2015. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var fromDate = DateTime.Now;           // set here your from date
var toDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7);  // set here your to date                
for (DateTime date = fromDate; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(date);
}
```

EDIT:

If you are using `DateTimePicker` for `toDate` and `fromDate` then try this

```
var fromDate = date_from.Value;  // Don't use date_from.Text as you mentioned in comments
var toDate = date_to.Value;
for (DateTime date = fromDate; date <= toDate; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(date);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, How can I see the var fromDate = date_from.Text; and toDate = date_to.Text;?

Comment: Sir, the date is right but it only show the last count

Comment: Sir everything's working now! Thanks for the help. God bless sir! :D